# no modification for data fied in civiEvent

Tags: civievent, civimember, profile, user-account, fields

We have just activated our CiviEvent module. 
We propose for registred users 
to use their own information or register other participant
But we don't want they can change their name (caps are important for exemple), mail or other fields.
How is it possible?

Best

Nicolas